# Binding WinForms chart to an Excel column

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview, charts

I need to create an app with a chart control. And I need to bind that chart control to a specific column of an Excel spreadsheet. So far I have bound a datagridview to the column. But the column contains integers, nulls, and strings. How do I extract just the integers from that column?
Here is the code:

```
DataTable dt = getDataFromXLS(@"C:\myFile.xlsx");
            if (dt != null)
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                //chart1.DataSource = dt;

private DataTable getDataFromXLS(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                            "Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                OleDbConnection cnCSV = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
                cnCSV.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(@"Select F9 From [Sheet1$]", cnCSV);
                DataTable dtCSV = new DataTable(); 
                OleDbDataAdapter daCSV = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                daCSV.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;
                daCSV.Fill(dtCSV);
                cnCSV.Close();
                daCSV = null;

                return dtCSV;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
            finally { }
        }
```

Comment: In the OleDBCommand, 'F9' is the column I'm interested in.

Comment: You can see from your post alone that there's a " mismatch. Not sure if this is related to your issue but it won't help things.

Comment: can you enlighten me on the mismatch?

Comment: Look at your post, you can see from the change of colour where the mistmatch is. **OleDbCommand cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(@"Select F9 From [Sheet1$], cnCSV);** < That line.

Comment: edited post to remove mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. configured the chart to ignore text and null values instead.